# My iPhone app loads very slowly

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I am working on an iPhone app. I use Touch Json to parse the PHP web service returning the Json data. The web service is called on the button's click event.

The web service is parsed in almost 10 seconds but the response is really slow.

As soon as the response is parsed, new view must be pushed.

The response is parsed in almost 10 seconds but it takes a minute to move to the next view.

I need to fix this issue as soon as possible.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you profiled your application within Instruments?

Answer (score 0):

Just as basic idea, do you use multithreading? You should implement something like this.

```
dispatch_queue_t myqueue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(myqueue, ^{
        //load your Json data here ex [dataManager loadData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //post a notification here for the table/view controller that needs to reload data  
    });
});
```

Now, you can push to the new viewcontroller even before calling this block, and add an observer for the notification to reload data. The segue will be instant, and your data will be available after 10 secs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support anything prior to iOS 5, you don't even need any third party libraries for parsing JSON anymore. You can just do this:

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];

if ( response )
{
    NSString *exampleValue = [response objectForKey:@"exampleKey"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Also, as Calin pointed out, if you're processing a huge amount of data, it's wiser to do it on a separate thread.